# .valueAsDate returns day before .value for input type date

Tags: javascript, date

Does anyone know why using `.valueAsDate` returns the day before the date provided in the input?

```js
var result = function(){
  var date = document.getElementById('result').value;
  var dateAsDate = document.getElementById('result').valueAsDate;
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
  document.getElementById('dateAsDate').innerHTML = dateAsDate;
}
```

```html
<input id = 'result' type = date>
<button onclick = 'result();'>Result</button>
<div id = 'date'></div>
<div id = 'dateAsDate'></div>
```

Comment: You have the converse of the linked question's issue (getting rather than setting). When you use `valueAsDate`, the date returned is midnight on the given date UTC, [as defined here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#date-state-(type=date)) (you have to scroll down a bit). The default `toString` on a `Date` gives you the date/time as *local* time. If your timezone is GMT minus anything, that will be the previous day. You can use `toUTCString` to get a string using UTC from the `Date` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I swear I searched SO before posting.